# Restore Postgres backup from pgdump.dir

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-restore

I have been seeing *.pgdump directory mostly to get the backup and restore. But for my new project the backups are stored under `dbname<date>.pgdump.dir`

Under this directory, the backups are stored in this format:

```
18662.dat.gz
18676.dat.gz
18690.dat.gz
18703.dat.gz
18715.dat.gz
19656.dat.gz
19715.dat.gz
22751.dat.gz
23313.dat.gz
toc.dat
```

This looks new to me. I tried searching on google but couldn't find any appropriate result. Can anyone please help how we can restore above backup to my new database.

For normal .pgdump backups I used to run commands like:

```
pg_restore -U username -d dbname -1 filename.dump
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directory format dumps are restored with the same `pg_restore` conmand as custom format dumps. `pg_restore` recognizes the format automatically.

Use the name of the directory that contains the dump as argument to `pg_restore`.